# how to query with a join on non primary key column in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, join

suppose I have the following 3 tables:

**Facility**
id, name

**Processor**
id, facility_id, enabled

**Task**
id, facility_id, processor_id, name

I have queries that naturally join the **task** table with the **processor** table, but some **tasks** may not be linked to **processors** (i.e. task.processor_id may be null).
I want to run a query that pulls all tasks in facilities that are linked to an enabled processor.

In other words, the query should look like this:

**select task.name**

**from task, processor**

**where task.facility_id = processor.facility_id and processor.enabled = 1**

I use @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn annotations to naturally link **task** to **processor** and to **facility**.
There is also @ManytoOne and @JoinColumn on **processor** to **facility**.

How can I do it using hibernate criteria without resorting to native SQL?